# Replace word with line from file if found on it

Tags: .net, vb.net, replace, line, words

I have a text file with a massive amount of lines with this format:

**word1**-**word2**-**word2**

**anotherword1**-**anotherword2**-**anotherword3**

**differentword1**-**differentword2**-**differentword3**

And so on. And what I'm trying to do is that from the given text from a richbox text to loop through all words from it at the same time I'm looping through each lines from the text file.

And if any line contains the respective word from the richtextbox text then replace the word with the whole line. Like from the word **word1** *to* **word1-word2-word3.**

I've made a code which sometimes works fine, but not on all words. Just a few of them. So I'd say the code is broken:

```
For Each Line As String In File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\test.txt")
    Dim thisArray As String() = Line.Split("-"c)
        For Each s As String In thisArray
            For Each wordfromtext As String In RichTextBox1.Text.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                If wordfromtext = s Then
                    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(wordfromtext, Line)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: I would recommend putting the result in a variable every time. When done replace the textbox text with the variable.

Comment: It is still a total mess. For a few words works, for other won't and for a text with over 20 words doesn't work at all. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Public Sub replaceword(ByVal input As RichTextBox, ByVal output As RichTextBox, ByVal textsep As Char)
    output.Text = ""
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    tb.Multiline = True
    tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\test.txt")
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To input.Lines.Count - 1
        output.Text &= input.Lines(i).ToString & vbNewLine
        repln(output, int, tb.Lines(getextln(input.Lines(i).ToString, textsep)))
        int += 1
    Next
    For i1 As Integer = 0 To output.Lines.Count - 2
        Dim inln As String = input.Lines(i1)
        Dim ouln As String = output.Lines(i1)
        If Not ouln.Contains(inln) And ouln.Contains(textsep.ToString) Then
            repln(output, i1, inln)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function getextln(ByVal str As String, ByVal sep As Char) As Integer
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    tb.Multiline = True
    tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\test.txt")
    Dim lstb As New ListBox
    For Each l In tb.Lines
        lstb.Items.Add(l)
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstb.Items.Count - 1
        If lstb.Items.Item(i).ToString.Contains(str) Then
            Dim str1 As String() = lstb.Items.Item(i).ToString.Split(sep.ToString)
            For Each w In str1
                If w = str Then
                    Return i
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function

Public Sub repln(ByVal tb1 As RichTextBox, ByVal ln As Integer, ByVal strnew As String)
    Dim str1 As New List(Of String)
    Dim str2 As String = ""
    For Each l In tb1.Lines 'Add each line of input to the list
        str1.Add(l)
    Next
    str1.RemoveAt(ln) 'Remove the seleted line
    str1.Insert(ln, strnew) 'Fill the gap with the new text
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    For Each l1 In str1 'Output the list
        str2 &= l1 & vbNewLine
    Next
    str2 = str2.Substring(0, str2.Length - 2) 'Remove the final line
    tb1.Text = str2 'Send the edited text to the input
End Sub
```

Call It With:

```
replaceword(RichTextBox1, RichTextBox2, "-")
```

With sentence support :)

Every error you had its now gone, and the code is smaller !

If you want the output to be the same textbox as the input, tell it to me and i'll edit the answer (The code will be longer)

Comment: Haha. Thank you, but: http://prntscr.com/btgehg

It only works if I put only a single word, reviews only one time for example. I guess we'll never solve it.

Comment: @Netero - That can be fixed but you'll stop having sentence support and the words next to others will display under them :)

Comment: @Netero - here is the code but you lose sentence support: http://pastebin.com/raw/X3d91u65

Comment: No. :( It replace every word, but in such a disastrous manner.

Comment: If understood your problem i'm fixing it....... Although it's realy hard.

Comment: If you want to use only enter to seperate words its easy. If you want to use only space its easy too. If you want to use both but the space to be converted to enter (Like it's now) its easy too. But if you want to use both and you want both to behave normaly its very hard :)

Comment: Here is the code to split only on space: http://pastebin.com/raw/2iE0di6p.  Some times it works on enter too, but it has a problem with unknown words.

Answer (score 1):

Final Code:

```
Public Sub replacewordwithline(ByVal input As RichTextBox, ByVal sep As Char, Optional ByVal output As RichTextBox = Nothing)
    Dim tb As New TextBox 'Create a new textbox
    Dim orgstr As String = input.Text 'Make a backup of the input text
    tb.Multiline = True
    tb.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\test.txt") 'Set the textbox's text to the text file text
    Dim str1 As String() 'Create blank input word list
    Dim str3 As String = ""
    For Each l2 In input.Lines 'For each line in input...
        str3 &= l2 & "#" '...Add a '#' to the end of it
    Next
    str1 = str3.Split({"#"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 'Split the input to words
    For Each w1 In str1 'For each word in input
        For Each l1 In tb.Lines 'For each line in text file
            If l1.Contains(w1) Then 'If line contains input word
                Dim str2 As String() = l1.Split({sep}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 'Split text file line
                For Each w2 In str2 'For each word in text file line
                    If w1 = w2 Then 'If input word = text file word
                        repln(input, getln(input, w1), l1) 'Replace line
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Dim bla As Boolean = False
    Try
        If Not output.Name = "" Then 'If output exists
            bla = True
            output.Text = input.Text 'Set the output's text to the input's one
            input.Text = orgstr 'Reset the input's text to the original
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
    If bla = True Then 'Output Exists
        For i1 As Integer = 0 To output.Lines.Count - 1 'For each output line
            Dim inln As String = input.Lines(i1)
            Dim ouln As String = output.Lines(i1)
            If Not ouln.Contains(inln) And ouln.Contains(sep.ToString) Then 'If output line doesn't contain input line and contains the seperator
                repln(output, i1, inln) 'Replace line
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf bla = False Then 'Output Doesn't Exist
        Dim tb1 As New TextBox
        tb1.Text = orgstr
        For i1 As Integer = 0 To input.Lines.Count - 1 'For each input line
            Dim inln As String = tb1.Lines(i1)
            Dim ouln As String = input.Lines(i1)
            If Not ouln.Contains(inln) And ouln.Contains(sep.ToString) Then 'If input line doesn't contain original string line and contains the seperator
                repln(input, i1, inln) ' Replace line
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub repln(ByVal tb1 As RichTextBox, ByVal ln As Integer, ByVal strnew As String)
    Dim str1 As New List(Of String)
    Dim str2 As String = ""
    For Each l In tb1.Lines 'Add each line of input to the list
        str1.Add(l)
    Next
    str1.RemoveAt(ln) 'Remove the seleted line
    str1.Insert(ln, strnew) 'Fill the gap with the new text
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    For Each l1 In str1 'Output the list
        str2 &= l1 & vbNewLine
    Next
    str2 = str2.Substring(0, str2.Length - 2) 'Remove the final line
    tb1.Text = str2 'Send the edited text to the input
End Sub

Public Function getln(ByVal tb As RichTextBox, ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each l In tb.Lines 'For each line in input
        If l = str Then 'If input line text is the same as the selected string
            Return i 'Return input line number
        End If
        i += 1
    Next
End Function
```

Example: `replacewordwithline(RichTextBox1, "-")` will set the text seperator to '-' and will output the result to RichTextBox1.
`replacewordwithline(RichTextBox1, "|", RichTextBox2)` will set the text seperator to '|' and will output the resault to RichTextBox2. The `output` is optional (In this case `RichTextBox2`)

Now with sentense support :)

On the text file if you write something like:

`I'm a potato-I'm a tomatoe`

And on the program:

`I'm a tomatoe` Or `I'm a potato`

The program will output:

`I'm a potato-I'm a tomatoe`

`-` Depends On The Seperator.

---

Duplicate the sub caller:

Ex.

```
Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    replacewordwithline(RichTextBox1, "-")
End Sub
```

To

```
Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    replacewordwithline(RichTextBox1, "-")
    replacewordwithline(RichTextBox1, "-")
End Sub
```

P.S. Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but not as it should. It replace the found word in text with its specific line just one time for just one word. This need to work with all words.

Comment: I don't undersatnd what you want but have you tried: `replacewordwithline(True)` ?

Comment: I'm trying to create a tool which will look for all words from a textbox, and if that word from textbox is inside of test.txt file, replace the found word with the whole line of the found word from test.txt. In all that line will be only synonyms for that word. I'm trying to create a text spinner in other words :(

Comment: Nvm i understood what the problem is i'm trying to fix it...... I think

Comment: Thank you for your effort! You are a truly amazing person!

Comment: Thank you so much for spending such amount of time solving my problem. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Sometimes it just replace just the first word and sometimes it give me this error: http://prntscr.com/br9m8x

Comment: Just so you know, the 2 worst things you can do on SO is a) delete a [question which someone took the time to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297129/1070452) and b) delete a downvoted question (rather than fix it).

Comment: I'm sorry a friend of mine thought is was funny to delete it and when i left my computer he deleted it.

Comment: Okkk i finaly did it now without space splitting but with sentence support :)

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for your effort. It seems this kind of work is hard even for good programmers. Unfortunately here is the output: http://prntscr.com/brw1iv :(

Comment: @Netero - I fixed it but some times you need to press the button twice. The fix is to the bottom of the code :)

Comment: Thanks! But still doesn't work: http://prntscr.com/bs15t6, I think I'm doing something wrong. You did well done job BanForFun. Thank you! I will try to fix it by myself from now on.

Comment: @Netero - it's funny because if you write: eamings ↵ reviews ↵ reviews eamings: It works! (↵ Means enter)

Comment: If you fix it send me the code i want to see what i'm missing ;)

Comment: I sure will. Thank you!

Comment: @BanForFun I'm nearly close to the answer... check the answer to my own question. If only we could do this for every word and not just one :(

Comment: I will see it tomorrow.

Comment: @Netero - I posted another answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    Dim LSOS As Integer = Nothing
    Dim linelentgh As Integer = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\test.txt").Length
    Do Until LSOS >= linelentgh
        Dim line As String = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\test.txt").Skip(LSOS).Take(1).First()
        repl(line)
        LSOS += 1
    Loop
End Sub

Sub repl(ByVal line As String)
    Dim thisArray As String() = line.Split("|"c)
    For Each wordfromtext As String In Inputs.Text.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each s As String In thisArray
            If wordfromtext = s Then
                Output.Text = Inputs.Text.Replace(s, line)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This code works fine, no multiple replacing problems, no words mistakes... but it work just for the first word found on it...

Comment: Ok... I see.... Let me try something and i'll tell you. By the way: If I knew that you always wanted to output the text to another textbox i could make my code work :)

Comment: Do you always want to output the text to another textbox?

Comment: I potsed another answer.